Hover Hide-Visible Additional CSS not working in Wordpress website, but shows properly in Customize window
I have used icon-box element in my Wordpress website with free version of Elementor. I wanted to show icon and title in default and keep the description hidden. On hover, I want to change the color of the description and show the description.
I added the CSS code to Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS. It works when viewing in Customize window only. After Publishing it and opening the website in new tab or incognito tab, the description disappears by default but show on hover is not working. Only title font color is changing on hover.
I tried different options, it's like if title color change CSS code is above that of description, then title CSS code works and if I add description hide and show on hover code above title code, then description CSS code works but not title CSS code. Its like title and description CSS code is conflicting with each other. The one on top is only working.
How to solve this? Please help.
Additional CSS Code -
    /* Icon box description disappear */
.custom-hover-box .elementor-icon-box-description {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Icon box description appear on hover */
.custom-hover-box:hover .elementor-icon-box-description {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #0E8202 !important; /* <-- change color here */
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* More specific selector for title color change on hover */
.custom-hover-box:hover .elementor-icon-box-title .elementor-icon-box-title-text {
    color: #0E8202 !important; /* <-- change color here */
    transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
}

